# How can i find Last row in a gridview on RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {


            **if (e.Row.RowIndex >= gridview1.PageSize) // ROW FOOTER TOTAL**
            {

                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Firebrick;
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            }
        }
```

This code works sometimes, someone can help me

DM,cheers

Comment: what you want to do with that row?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to find the last column in the PreRender event

```
protected void grid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = grdAlert.Rows[grdAlert.Rows.Count - 1];

    // do stuff with your row
}
```

If you just need to change the style of the footer you can use

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" FooterStyle="your style"></asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

A grid view doesn't appear to have a row count until it's finished binding each row. So, another thought:

Can you determine the number of rows from the datatable that the gridview is binding to, then store that in a variable for use later?

you can find last row like this

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count-1];
```

or use this

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView)sender;

        if(e.Row.RowIndex == (grid.Rows.Count - 1))
         {
             //last row
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Test your code. The row count is alwais equal to the row index since you are adding rows. And i think you don't have to cast the sender object to a grid since you can access the controls in the aspx directly in the code behind

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to detect the footer row in `RowDataBound` since you have commented `//ROW FOOTER TOTAL`, you just have to check for the `DataControlRowType.Footer`:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        // here it is
    }
}
```

Otherwise you could compare the `RowIndex` with the row of the undrlying `DataItem`:

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
if (e.Row.RowIndex == row.DataView.Count - 1) ; // last row
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page load method set colors as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //code what you currently have ....
    // add below code after that
    GridViewRow row  = GridView1.Rows.Count-1;
    row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Firebrick;
    row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
}
```